# Casting a string with a list on list

Tags: pydantic

I am trying to create a Pydantic model to which I will parse JSON, but list is provided as a string. I have no control over what form it comes in, I prefer to avoid reworking the input.

This is what the sample message looks like:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "digits": "[4, 6, 3, 6, 8]"
}
```

I would like to cast them into models like this:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class DigitsResponse(BaseModel):
    status: str
    digits: List[int]

DigitsResponse.model_validate_json(json_input)
```

Of course it's failed with "Input should be a valid array". Any ideas how to cast from string to list?

As for now I tried multiple Pydantic's functions and tried submodel workaround, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the brackets off the list and split it, creating a list of strings. Then use map() to cast each element to a new list[int].
*EDIT: You should probably consider handling exceptions too, depending on your requirements.

```html
input={
    "status": "OK",
    "digits": "[4, 6, 3, 6, 8]"
}

output:list[int]=list(map(int,input["digits"].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(', ')))
```